# How to have foreverjs persist after logout?

Tags: node.js, express, forever

[This article ([1])](https://thomashunter.name/posts/2012-12-14-using-authbind-with-node-js) shows how to use foreverjs with authbind, but it is not clear to me whether or not the forever process will persist after logging out.

Is there an easy way to get foreverjs to persist after logging out?

Bonus question: is there an easy way to get foreverjs to survive a system restart?

[1] https://thomashunter.name/posts/2012-12-14-using-authbind-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
nohup forever ./server-index.js &
```

or with authbind:

```
authbind --deep nohup forever ./server-index.js &
```

Note that [reference [1]](https://thomashunter.name/posts/2012-12-14-using-authbind-with-node-js) recommends using a reverse proxy rather using authbind with Node.js on a production server.

[1] https://thomashunter.name/posts/2012-12-14-using-authbind-with-node-js